# how I get the html tags from the site from webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to get html tags.For ex www.google.com.
When I enter this site with in android webview.
How I get this? 
But how I get html from webview?

Comment: Why you need to have HTML tags and then load it with loadData()?. Instead you can directly load the URL by using **loadURL() directly**.

Comment: I need only html tags from webview in android how I get it

Comment: for ex I entered www.google.com in android webview and I want to html tags from my webview . How I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://whatever.com/thingie");
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
StringEntity ent = new StringEntity("Here is my data!");
post.setEntity(ent);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

**More information :** [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170855/how-to-access-a-web-content-post-get-in-an-android-application)

Then you can convert content of response to String using

```
private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String s = "";
    String line = "";

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // Read response until the end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { s += line; }

    // Return full string
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I want to only html tags from webview in android

Comment: for ex I entered www.google.com in android webview and I want to html tags from my webview . How I do it?

Comment: why I cant ask question again?